# Change key [ 0 ] to [ Name ] in php array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have array:

```
[0] => Height: 3/16 
[1] => Color: Standard Red 
[2] => Material: Die-cut, pressure-sensitive paper
```

I want to remove these number keys(0,1,2) And replace them with string before two dots in array elements values. So the final result will be:

```
[Height] => 3/16 
[Color] => Standard Red 
[Material] => Die-cut, pressure-sensitive paper
```

I tried to solve this with array_values function but i didnt make it, can someone help me?

Comment: Is the value of the keys (0, 1, 2) a string? "Height: 3/16" for example?

Comment: Please add what you tried. Also how is the first array generated, probably easier to fix it at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to process your array. Inside the function we use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to split the string into its component parts (note you could probably just use `explode(':', $v)` and `trim` instead).

```
$array = array('Height: 3/16',
               'Color: Standard Red',
               'Material: Die-cut, pressure-sensitive paper');
$new_array = array_reduce($array, 
     function ($c, $v) { preg_match('/^([^:]+):\s+(.*)$/', $v, $m); 
                         return array_merge($c, array($m[1] => $m[2]));
                       },
     []);
print_r($new_array);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [Height] => 3/16
    [Color] => Standard Red
    [Material] => Die-cut, pressure-sensitive paper
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/egoMN)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input =
[
    'Height: 3/16',
    'Color: Standard Red',
    'Material: Die-cut, pressure-sensitive paper'
];

foreach($input as $v) {
    list($key, $val) = explode(':', $v, 2);
    $output[$key] = trim($val);
}

var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'Height' => '3/16',
    'Color' => 'Standard Red',
    'Material' => 'Die-cut, pressure-sensitive paper',
)
```